# Using translate and calc() together

Tags: css, css-position, absolute, calc

I have an element which I vertically position as follows:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%)
```

This pops it straight in the middle of the screen. The problem is that I have a footer, so the div always has to be a further 150px higher to center the div.

Is there a way to combine a sass function or calc() to get my div to move up?

Comment: does the problem happen when scrolling down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now most of the modern browsers supports `calc()` on `top` as well as in inside `translateY`. Check below snippet for reference. For browser support check here in [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(calc(-50% - 50px));
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use calc with your top:

```
top: calc(50% - 150px);
```

Alternatively a negative margin could work:

```
margin-top: -150px;
```